# Title not displaying correctly on flexibleSpaceBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I'm trying to show the title but as you can see, it does not do it correctly.

[image]

I tried to put softWrap to true but it is still the same.

The code is from [flutter contacts_demo gallery](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/contacts_demo.dart#L159)

```
flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          title: const Text('Fantastic Beasts And Where To Find Them'),
            background: Stack(
               fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(
                  'people/ali_landscape.png',
                  package: 'flutter_gallery_assets',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  height: _appBarHeight,
                ),
                // This gradient ensures that the toolbar icons are distinct
                // against the background image.
                const DecoratedBox(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment(0.0, -1.0),
                      end: Alignment(0.0, -0.4),
                      colors: <Color>[Color(0x60000000), Color(0x00000000)],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: how do you want it to look like ?

Comment: The position is ok, I just want to show the whole title

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `ConstrainedBox` along with `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`

```
final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);

final availableWidth = mediaQuery.size.width - 160;
```

along with

```
title: ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxWidth: availableWidth,
    ),
    child: const Text('Fantastic Beasts And Where To Find Them'),
),
```

Comment: @Guillaume Honestly, I just tested a few values and 160 looked nice on my screen.

Comment: @Guillaume I posted below my findings on why that `160` was needed above. It will work only for 320dp wide screens, you should divide by `1.5` to get it working everywhere. Until there's a proper fix someday.

Answer (score 6):

I dug into a `FlexibleSpaceBar` sources and at least now I understand what happens. Turns out that in an expanded state `title` is scaled up to be `1.5` of its size, so naturally it will overflow offscreen. As user scrolls up, `title` is scaled down towards its source size of `1.0`. At this size it will sit in the top toolbar.

Maybe this information will help someone to base their workarounds on until this is fixed.

I wondered why my hack of wrapping title in `ConstraintedBox` with `maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` didn't work. Now I know: I must divide this  `maxWidth` by `1.5`.

See also [this bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14227) on the Flutter github issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

The title length in combination with the font size you've set have no way to be displayed on a single line on smaller devices, for obvious reasons.

You may want to play with `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` to get the device width and set the header text fontSize accordingly as a fraction of that. Try in the emulator to see which works best for your text length.

```
const Text(
    'Fantastic Beasts And Where To Find Them', 
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/ SOME_NUMBER),
),
```

Or just hardcode some font sizes based on some width intervals:

```
int _getFontSize(BuildContext context) {
    int width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    if (width < 300) {
        return 10;
    } else if (width < 600) {
        return 13;
    // etc ...
    } else {
        return 18;
    }

}

...

const Text(
    'Fantastic Beasts And Where To Find Them', 
    style: _getFontSize(context),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dimsuz's answer it is possible to eliminate the upscaling of text in a `FlexibleSpaceBar`:

```
SliverAppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.save),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
        floating: true,
        pinned: false,
        snap: false,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          title: Text(title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0 / 1.5)),
          centerTitle: false,
          background: Container(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          ),
        ),
        expandedHeight: 120,
      ),
```

The `20.0` in `fontSize` I took from [here](https://learnui.design/blog/android-material-design-font-size-guidelines.html).